# Package a Folder in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm looking to make a program to make my life easier, I need to be able to easily select a folder, which I can do, I don't need help with that. I want to take the directory of a folder, and put that folder into a new folder with a specified name, and then zip up that folder into a zip format in which I can change the name and filetype of. Is this possible in vanilla C#? I've only ever done files for text and I've never looked at moving and packaging files. SO I'm really clueless, I'd just like to be guided into the right direction.

Edit: I found this code online, but I need to put the folder inside another folder, may I adapt upon this to do so?

```
string startPath = @"c:\example\start";
string zipPath = @"c:\example\result.zip";
string extractPath = @"c:\example\extract";

ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(startPath, zipPath);
ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(zipPath, extractPath);
```

Comment: Try this:  [Microsoft Docs - System.IO.Directory.Move](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.move?view=net-6.0)

Comment: @TalinTheDev I can't seem to figure out how I would get that to work, how would I get to the right place in my path string (Before the last folder) and shove the string name in there to actually move the folder?

Comment: Here's an example, I have this: C:\Program Files\Android I need to get C:\Program Files\ProgramArchive\Android

Comment: So you need to move the first folder to the second one? Or the other way around.

Comment: What do you mean by "I need to get"?

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel that's the result string I need

Also getting another error: I get "System.UnauthorizedAccessException: 'Access to the path 'D:\' is denied.'" whenever trying to run CreateFromDirectory

Comment: Your requirements are still really vague. Where is that destination path coming from? Is it user input? Is it constructed from user input?

Comment: Basically, you would get the string from this path by pressing the browse button on my application, choosing the path, and the application would now have that path as a string. so "C:\Program Files\Android". I need to use this code:
string startPath = textBox1.Text;
string zipPath = System.IO.Directory.GetParent(startPath).ToString();
ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(startPath, zipPath);

To somehow put that folder at that path, into a new folder, and zip it up.

Comment: Well, seems like you almost got it. You have the path of the input directory, the path of the destination zip, and the code that zips it. What's blocking you?

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel First of all, I don't seem to have access to the directory 'Access to the path 'D:\' is denied.', it says and I also need to put the folder, in a new folder with a custom name before zipping.

Comment: I just have no idea how to go about doing those last two things

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241808/discussion-between-etienne-de-martel-and-bruh).

Comment: If you find the solution, you could click '✔' to mark it as an answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve a similar issue. See also [stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, after an extended chat discussion, here's what we've established.

The goal is to put the contents of a source directory into a zip with the following structure:

```
- Payload
|- name of source
|-- contents of source
```

Okay, so, starting from an input path called `startPath`:

```
var parent = Path.GetDirectoryName(startPath);

var payload = Path.Combine(parent, "payload");
Directory.CreateDirectory(payload); // ensure payload ex
Directory.Move(startPath, Path.Combine(payload, Path.GetFileName(startPath));

var zipPath = Path.Combine(parent, "export.zip");
File.Delete(zipPath);
ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(payload , zipPath, CompressionLevel.Optimal, true);
```

The key is that `true` in the `CreateFromDirectory` call, that puts the entries in the archive under a directory with the same name as the directory being zipped (in this case, "payload"). Feel free to change `CompressionLevel` to other values if you want.

Now, this has the side effect of actually physically moving the source directory, which might not be the best user experience. If you want to avoid that, you'll have to basically do what `ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory` does by hand, which is to enumerate the source directory yourself and then copy the files into the zip archive (in which case you can name those files whatever you want):

```
    var parent = Path.GetDirectoryName(startPath);
    
    var zipPath = Path.Combine(parent, "export.zip");
    File.Delete(zipPath);

    using var zip = ZipFile.Open(zipPath, ZipArchiveMode.Create);
    
    foreach(var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(startPath, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
    {
        // get the path of the file relative to the parent directory
        // this gives us a path that starts with the source directory name
        // e.g. C:\example\start\file.txt -> start\file.txt
        var relativePath = Path.GetRelativePath(parent, file);
        
        // construct the path of the entry in the archive
        // this is "Payload", and then the relative path of the file
        // we need to fix up the separators because zip entries use /
        // e.g. start\file.txt -> Payload/start/file.txt
        var entryPath = Path.Combine("Payload", relativePath).Replace(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar, '/');
        
        // put the file in the archive
        // to specify a compression level, pass it as the third parameter here
        zip.CreateEntryFromFile(file, entryPath);
    }
```